# How to create Excel histogram from frequency table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, data-visualization

I have an Excel table with two rows.

One header row with positive integers representing different event properties and another row with the frequency of events with said property number.

Here's a snippet of said table (ignore the second column):

[image: Table Snippet]

I want to create a histogram where the top row is aggregated into different bins and then have each bin's corresponding frequency. For example, bin [0,5] would have the frequency 1+75+1284+1943+1632+377 = 5312.

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: This site is not a free scripting site. If you have tried something and it did not work, share your code/scripts so we can help you debug it. But as it stands, this question will most likely be closed for lack of showing effort.

Comment: Have a look at the Frequency() Excel function, and come back when you've tried that...

Comment: @Paul I fail to see how the Frequency() function might be of any use here. Care to elucidate?

Comment: You are right, you already have the frequencies in this case, you just want to aggregate them further. In that case, you would use the SUMIF() function: for any bin, sum all numbers where the event property is less or equal to the bin limit, minus the same for the previous bin limit. Have a try...